# How to apply for loop to create charts using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, charts

I have 14 pivot tables.I want to create charts for all 14 tables.My code is given below which looks so wired.I want to apply for loop here.My code is given below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("B5:E5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$3:$E$5")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht1 As Shape
    Set cht1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht1.Name = "chart001"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart001").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart001").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart001").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue




    Range("B12:D12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$10:$D$12")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht2 As Shape
    Set cht2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht2.Name = "chart002"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart002").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels

    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart002").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart002").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B19:E19").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$17:$E$19")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht3 As Shape
    Set cht3 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht3.Name = "chart003"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart003").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart003").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart003").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B26:E26").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$24:$E$26")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht4 As Shape
    Set cht4 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht4.Name = "chart004"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart004").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart004").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart004").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B33:E33").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$31:$E$33")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht5 As Shape
    Set cht5 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht5.Name = "chart005"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart005").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart005").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart005").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B40:E40").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$38:$E$40")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht6 As Shape
    Set cht6 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht6.Name = "chart006"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart006").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart006").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart006").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B47:E47").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$45:$E$47")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht7 As Shape
    Set cht7 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht7.Name = "chart007"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart007").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart007").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart007").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B54:E54").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$52:$E$54")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht8 As Shape
    Set cht8 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht8.Name = "chart008"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart008").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart008").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart008").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


    Range("B59:E59").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$59:$E$61")
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht9 As Shape
    Set cht9 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht9.Name = "chart009"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart009").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart009").Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart009").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
End Sub
```

I have 14 different pivot tables. Now how can I apply a for loop or any other loop to minimize the length of the code. I am new here so not finding out any solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this: 
As the only difference between your graphs is the range you select.

```
Sub test()

Dim k, i As Integer

i = 0

For k = 1 To 12

Range(Cells(5 + i * 7, 2 + i * 7), Cells(5 + i * 7, 5 + i * 7)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets("Pivot").Cells(1, 3), Sheets("Pivot").Cells(5 + i * 7, 5 + i * 7))
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    Dim cht1 As Shape
    Set cht1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht1.Name = "chart00" & k
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart00" & k).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart00" & k).Width = 288
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("chart00" & k).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

i = 0 + 1
Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

that could be something like:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 13
        Range("B5:E5").Offset(i * 7).Select
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
            With .Chart
                .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$3:$E$5").Offset(i * 7)
                .SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
                .SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
                .SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
                .ShowValueFieldButtons = False
            End With
            .Name = "chart" & Format(i + 1, "000")
            .Width = 288
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

just be informed the 2nd range in your code differs from the column pattern of all others (B:D and A:D instead of B:E and A:E)

Comment: @Shaon, any feedback?

Comment: @DispalyName: Thanks.This Code works fine but some issues are there and I got 1004 error. My second and last pivot has only two data levels..So When choosing the range for that it didn't find any range for that and 1004 error will come up.How to resolve this?

Comment: This is a completely different issue from the one you started this topic for. If my answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted and start a new topic for a new issue. Thank you